# What transition metal ions form without oxidant in water pH 7?

Tags: elements

I am not sure how many transition metals will ionize without oxidants, where could I learn this?

Comment: They don't react in such situation at all.

Comment: @Mithoron ...unless water is intended to be the oxidant as with alkali and some alkaline earth metals.

Comment: @OscarLanzi We both know what OP meant, but on the other hand I doubt if he asked about lanthanides.

Answer (score 2):

If you are counting lanthanides as "transition metals", then look at europium whose reactivity with water is [similar to calcium](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europium).  Although the product listed in the reference is the trivalent hydroxide $\ce{Eu(OH)3}$, europium has a relativy stable +2 oxidation state and so the reaction msy proceed via a relatively soluble divalent hydroxide or cation ($\ce{Eu(OH)2, Eu^{2+}}$).  The combination of a highly electropositive element, possibly with formation of a relatively soluble, low oxidation state hydroxide/cation makes europium more reactive to water than most transition metals.

Comment: Very nice info for europium. I am hoping for a reference where i might learn this sort of info for any transition metal.

Comment: If only this were for pH 7: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_oxidation_states_of_the_elements